# Calculate interval between two dates with two columns each

Tags: excel, time

I need to calculate a time interval, where my data is arranged the following way:
I have column A with a date of the start of a event, and colum B with the hour:minute start of the event. The same for C with date of end of a event,  and D with the hour:minute end of the event.
I want to calculate the diferences in minutes between the start and end.  The start date can be in diferent days and months, so i can't just substract the time.

Comment: (C+D)-(A+B)? Or (D-B)? Can you show some sample data with desired output? Not clear what you need

Answer (score 2):

To get the answer in **minutes** use:

```
=24*60*((C1+D1)-(A1+B1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Excel integers is days and the decimals is the time of the day.
With that in mind:

```
=(C1+D1)-(A1+B1)
```

Then you need to set the formatting of the cell to suit your needs.

Edit: just to explain, you can set the formatting to custom and use `[m]` to sum the minutes.